# Como funcionam os números de serie em um sistema?

Tags: banco-de-dados, lógica

Sabe quando você faz uma compra de um jogo online e recebe a CD-KEY, e então abre um aplicativo e registra essa CD-KEY pra você? Ou então você comprou seu novo Sistema Operacional e vai registrar e insere uma key e mesmo offline ela é aceita? Como elas são feitas afinal?

São apenas um banco de dados enorme contendo todas as keys válidas e para quem foram atribuídas, ou existe uma lógica por trás disso?

Acredito que não seja uma pergunta ampla, pois deve haver algum algoritmo ou padrão utilizado que responda a essa pergunta.

Comment: Eu não posso dizer com certeza o que é usado na prática, já que são sistemas proprietários e eu não conheço seu funcionamento. Mas posso afirmar com segurança que é baseado em criptografia. O esquema pode ser desde simples - o software contém uma chave pública, e o CD-KEY é uma chave privada ou algo assinado com essa chave - até algo bem mais complexo. Já estudei por exemplo uma técnica que permite "desabilitar" um dispositivo crackeado simplesmente gerando um código que funciona em todos os outros menos naquele. Também posso inferir algumas coisas baseado na experiência pessoal com o Windows.

Comment: A propósito, eu acho a pergunta interessante, só não sei se é "respondível". Você diz que deve haver algum algoritmo ou padrão, mas dificilmente esse padrão seria **público** - pois do contrário, ia facilitar muito o trabalho dos "piratas" rsrs.

Comment: Em inglês: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3002067/how-are-software-license-keys-generated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Não há padrão. Cada empresa faz de um jeito, com maior ou menor nível de sofisticação/qualidade. Raramente o algoritmo é publicado, uma vez que o desconhecimento do mesmo é o principal fator que busca (mas raramente consegue) assegurar a proteção contra o uso indevido (ver ["segurança por obscurantismo"](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seguran%C3%A7a_por_obscurantismo)). As técnicas empregadas evoluem com o tempo, ao mesmo tempo que as técnicas de "quebra" ou evasão* também o fazem.

Entretanto, pode-se observar alguns padrões nessas técnicas, dependendo do cenário em particular que elas se aplicam (software online ou offline, que "liga pra casa" ou que não liga).

> ***Nota:** me refiro a "quebra" quando se descobre um meio de se gerar códigos válidos que não foram emitidos pelo produtor/distribuidor, sem alteração ("crack") no programa, e a "evasão" quando o programa é modificado para simplesmente não fazer mais a checagem da chave (de modo que funcione sem uma chave válida) ou para "enganá-lo" de qualquer outra forma, simulando um servidor de valiadação, bloquando o aplicativo no firewall, etc.

### Offline, sem "*call home*"

Nesse cenário procura-se impedir que um usuário que não possua a chave - qualquer chave - execute o programa. É o cenário mais simples, porém mais limitado - pois basta que uma única chave seja divulgada para que qualquer um com uma cópia do programa possa usá-la.

A técnica geral é embutir no software um algoritmo verificador, que recebe um código e diz "válido" ou "inválido", e separadamente entregar ao cliente uma chave única que o validador aceitará. O formato tem de ser tal que um terceiro não possa facilmente criar códigos válidos a partir do nada.

Já se usou algoritmos bastante ineficazes em sistemas mais antigos (uma resposta a [uma pergunta semelhante no SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3002067/520779) [indicada por rubStackOverflow nos comentários] cita um caso em que apenas 10 tentativas eram suficientes para adivinhar uma chave válida!), mas alguém que quisesse implementar isso hoje em dia poderia fazê-lo de forma inquebrável (mas não inevasível) através da criptografia de chave pública:

- Crie um par de chaves, embutindo a chave pública na mídia de instalação;
- Cada licença teria um número de série, e a CD-Key seria esse número de série assinado pela chave privada (que só o distribuidor tem);
- Quando o usuário entrar com a chave, o sistema só tem que verificar se a assinatura é válida ou não.

Sem a chave privada, é impossível criar um [*keygen*](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keygen) que gere (com alta probabilidade) chaves válidas, não importa quantas outras chaves o atacante conheça. De modo que a única maneira de copiar o software sem alterá-lo seria reutilizar uma chave já usada (e se o fornecedor tem meios de rastrear uma chave ao seu dono - via registro no ato da compra, por exemplo - isso aumenta a exposição de quem compartilha uma chave, e consequentemente o risco de ser pego).

### Offline, "*calling home*"

Se a ativação do produto envolve a intervenção do produtor/distribuidor, isso permite uma proteção um pouco mais sofisticada. Pode-se por exemplo fazer com que o software só funcione na primeira máquina em que foi instalado, e que o código seja inútil em qualquer outra*. Além é claro de tentar autenticar quem usa o CD-Key, de modo a evitar que a mesma chave seja usada duas vezes por pessoas diferentes.

> * ***disclaimer:*** ao menos no Brasil e nos EUA isso é ilegal (por razões diferentes), a menos que o fornecedor garanta ao consumidor o direito de reinstalar o sistema em outra máquina (após desinstalar da primeira, ou se a primeira estiver inutilizável), seja qual for o meio técnico usado pra tal. No Brasil é permitido até mesmo [**crackear um sistema legalmente**](http://boingboing.net/2010/07/10/brazils-copyright-la.html) para garantir seus direitos de consumidor, desde que esse crack não incorra simultaneamente numa violação dos direitos autorais do fornecedor.

Essa intervenção não precisa necessariamente envolver conexão com a internet, como já observado (recentemente validei minha cópia do Windows 7 por telefone). De novo, as técnicas variam em qualidade, mas segue um exemplo de como isso poderia ser feito:

- De novo, chaves assimétricas são criadas, mas nesse caso *dois* pares são necessários, um pra assinar e outro pra cifrar;
- Um CD-Key é criado tal como no caso anterior, assinado pelo fabricante;
- O software, após instalado, coleta algumas informações sobre o sistema do usuário difíceis de serem forjadas (como seu [endereço MAC](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endere%C3%A7o_MAC)) e pede o CD-Key pro usuário (verificando a assinatura);
- Ele então cifra ("encripta") ambos os dados gerando um novo código, que precisa ser enviado de volta pro fabricante (seja via internet, telefone, ou qualquer outro meio);
- O fabricante então decifra esses dados, cadastra-os no seu banco de dados (como dito, "um banco de dados enorme contendo todas as keys válidas e para quem foram atribuídas") - caso já não tenham sido usadas, é claro - efetivamente ligando (*locking*) aquele número serial àquele usuário e àquela máquina específica;
- Um código de liberação específico praquele serial é criado então, e assinado pelo fabricante; esse código é então inserido no software (automaticamente ou manualmente) e a assinatura é verificada, liberando o acesso.

De novo o atacante não pode gerar um CD-Key do nada (pois não tem a chave privada de assinatura), mas nesse caso não dá nem pra reusar uma chave anterior - pois o código final, aquele retornado no final do processo, só é válido pro computador com aquele endereço MAC específico.

### Online

Se o software exigir conexão com a internet, então nada disso é necessário - basta usar um valor aleatório e único como CD-Key (um UUID basta, desde que [gerado de forma segura](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/CSPRNG)), guardá-lo no seu banco de dados *a priori* (necessário, do contrário não se poderia distinguir chaves válidas de inválidas) e na hora de validar checar se o código está no banco e associá-lo ao usuário logado (se isso já não tiver sido feito), rejeitando se ele for enviado por um usuário diferente. E é claro tomando as medidas cabíveis para evitar que múltiplas pessoas façam login com a mesma conta de usuário.